# How to get documents from other collections within a collection that match the values ​of the elements of a list field

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have two collections,
one is project collection
other is batch collection

two collection looks like this

Collection "project":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6102780c27474af56cf6734b"),
    "channel" : "instagram",
    "status" : "new",
    "analysis_type" : "detail",
    "batch_ids" : [ 
        "6102780c27474af56cf6734d", 
        "6102780d27474af56cf6734f", 
        "6102780d27474af56cf67351", 
        "6102780e27474af56cf67353", 
        "6102780e27474af56cf67355", 
        "6102780e27474af56cf67357"
    ]
}
```

Collection "batch":

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("6102780c27474af56cf6734d"),
    "keyword" : {
        "keyword" : "tomato",
        "keyword_type" : "hashtag"
    },
    "channel" : "instagram",
    "post_datetime" : ISODate("2021-07-29T18:42:36.306Z"),
    "analysis_type" : "detail",
    "status" : "new",
}
```

A project contains multiple batch. So, in the field called batch_ids, I wrote down which batches the project contains.
Each element of the batch_ids field is the value of the _id field of the batch collection. I want to see the status of batches belonging to a project at once.
How do I create a view? The result I want to see is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6102780c27474af56cf6734b"),
    "channel" : "instagram",
    "status" : "new",
    "analysis_type" : "detail",
    "batch_ids" : [ 
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("6102780c27474af56cf6734d"),
         "status":"new"
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("6102780d27474af56cf6734f"),
         "status":"new"
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("6102780d27474af56cf67351"),
         "status":"new"
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("6102780e27474af56cf67353"),
         "status":"new"
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("6102780e27474af56cf67355"),
         "status":"new"
        },
        {
         "_id":ObjectId("6102780e27474af56cf67357"),
         "status":"new"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `$lookup` should suffice:

```
db.project.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "batch",
      "let": {
        batchObjectIds: {
          $map: {
            input: "$batch_ids",
            as: "batch_id",
            in: {
              "$toObjectId": "$$batch_id"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$batchObjectIds"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            status: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "batch_ids"
    }
  }
])
```

*Note that because you're saving the `batch_ids` as `string` and not `objectId` we have to cast them to `ObjectId` using [toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) meaning this can only work for Mongo v4.0+. If you're on a lesser Mongo version you will have to split this into 2 calls.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IlTz2pznDW8)

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful.